# What causes choppy Flash Video

Tags: flash

I have an I7 7700k with 64 GB DDR4 running at 14-14-14-34 and an Nvidia GTX 1070 GPU so I'm pretty sure it's not a hardware issue.  I've tried updating Flash and Chrome to the latest version and disabling hardware acceleration to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried disabling flash entirely and seeing if the site falls back to html5 video?

Comment: Flash causes choppy Flash video. If you are not using an AdBlocker such as uBlock origin then all of the Flash-based ads on the page are consuming resources and slowing your computer.